# Dreaming obout a dead mother

Tags: tafseer, death, dream

Asalamu alikum.
My aunt saw a dream today in which she saw her dead mother (my grandmother) . In that dream my aunt says that we have built a new house thats resembling to a aeroplane and has a trolly near. Her dead mother places her in that trolly and says to go while my aunt asks her dead mother that this trolly is uncomfortable andneither can she  move in  it nor  can she get out of it. Today my aunt isnt feeing well she is usually ill and today she said that she feels extremely uneasy and thinks something is going to happen to her. What does this dream interpret?

Comment: Dream interpretation is off-topic.